# How to add annotation in Mapview with image and label in IPhone?

Tags: ios, dictionary, annotations

[image: image1]        [image: image here]

I am using MKMapview in my iPhone app.

How can I assign values in annotation in MKMapkit Framework?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use custom view for each annotation with one `UIView`, one `UIImageView` and one Label to display different value. This will be done within the method `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)newMapView viewForAnnotation:(id )newAnnotation`. You have to take `UIView` double in size with transparent color with respect to `UIImageView` to make more precise view on zoom in and zoom out in mapview.

Code-----

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString * const kPinAnnotationIdentifier = @"PinIdentifier";
    if(annotation == self._mapView.userLocation)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation  = (MyAnnotation *)annotation;
    MKAnnotationView *newAnnotation = (MKAnnotationView*)[self._mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:kPinAnnotationIdentifier];

    if(!newAnnotation){
        newAnnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:@"userloc"];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict=[alertInfoArray objectAtIndex:myAnnotation.ann_tag];
    UIView *anView=[[UIView alloc] init];
    anView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    UIImageView *bgImg=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    bgImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    bgImg.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imgView.tag=myAnnotation.ann_tag;

    UILabel *lblName=[[UILabel alloc] init];
    lblName.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    lblName.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lblName.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    lblName.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lblName.text=TEXT YOU WANT ;

    newAnnotation.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 212);
    anView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 212);
    bgImg.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 106);
    bgImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb-needhelp.png"];

    imgView.frame=CGRectMake(8,25,55,48);
    imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"girl-default.png"];
    lblName.frame=CGRectMake(5,79,60,10);



    [anView addSubview:bgImg];
    [bgImg release];
    [anView addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];
    [newAnnotation addSubview:anView];
    [anView release];

    newAnnotation.canShowCallout=YES;
    [newAnnotation setEnabled:YES];

    return newAnnotation;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the format of data stored in the alertInfoArray and in which function can we give tag to annotation

Comment: Can we get a swift version please?

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a custom Annotation class (`MKAnnotation`)
2. Create a custom AnnotationView class (`MKAnnotationView`)

Make sure you define the title, background image, and other elements of your custom annotation in the `AnnotationView` class as properties.

1. Override the following method, and set the values of the properties you defined in `AnnotationView` class.

   ```
   - (MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

   if ([<Object of CustomAnnotation class> isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
       return nil;

   CustomAnnotation* custom_anno = (CustomAnnotation*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"custom_annotation"];

   if (!custom_anno){
   custom_anno = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"custom_annotation"];
   custom_anno.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 57.5);

   custom_anno.canShowCallout = NO;//CHange if you want to change callout behaviour (thats is it's abilty to apper). I set it top no because i did not want a callout.

   UIImageView* icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40)];
   [icon setImageWithURL:<your image> placeholderImage:<your placeholder image>];//placeholder image = nil if you do not want one.
   icon.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

   UILabel* name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 5, 200, 20)];
   name.text = nameValue;

   UILabel* category = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 25, 200, 20)];
   category.text = otherValue;

   [custom_anno addSubview:icon];
   [custom_anno addSubview:name];
   [custom_anno addSubview:category];
   }
   return custom_anno;
   }
   ```

   My custom annotation class was 'Annotation' and custom annotation view class was 'CustomAnnotation'. Change according to your needs.

After this, just create an object of the `Annotation`class, and use it.

EDIT :

Make sure you override the follwing method int he custom annotation view class:

in .h:

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
```

in .m:

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
}
return self;
```

}

EDIT 2 :

You may use it in your view controller like this :

```
MKMapView* cellMap = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 100)];
cellMap.delegate = self;
cellMap.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(<your coordinates>);
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.04, 0.04);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
cellMap.showsUserLocation = NO;
[cellMap setRegion:region animated:YES];

Annotation* anon = [[Annotation alloc] init];
anon.coordinate = center;

[cellMap addAnnotation:anon];
[checkIn addSubview:cellMap];
```